# Shirt Designer tool jquery css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a help  , i want to make a shirt design tool where users able to select each part of an shirt image and then they will chose different type of febric and the perticular portion of the shirt image will change to that febric.

is it possibile to make with jquery. please help me

reference http://www.shirtsmyway.com/design_myshirt.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Your question is too broad, you need to mention your technology stack, weather you are storing pre-processed images or you want to generate images through image processing.

1)If you are using pre-processed images for all possible design combinations, you can easily do it with JQuery. 
2) If you want to generate images on runtime, you would want to do some server side image processing. [Here](https://www.suitposh.com/design-shirt?button=272&collar=16&contrast=&cuff=105&fabric=240&placket=120&sleeve=25) is a good example which uses mix of pre and post processing for this purpose.

Comment: Thankyou sir for your reply.  Pls let me know, is it possible to create the part of images with different febric dynamicly??